# Why is my Visual Studio 2010 New Project dialog broken?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I came back from MIX 11, installed the new MVC Tools update, and now my Visual Studio 2010 New Project dialog looks like this. This is a serious problem that I have been unable to resolve after a full remove & reinstall of VS 2010 Ultimate. System restores have been unable to resolve this issue either.

I've also tried running devenv /installvstemplates, nothing seems to work.

Also, when opening an existing project, the Add Library Package Reference command causes error "TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY".

This is a SERIOUS PROBLEM, please help!

[image: Visual Studio New Project dialog screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your %temp% folder, there should be a file called MVCVS2010Templates.log, or something similar.

It contains the result of running devenv /setup and will show whether VS decided to remove packages or encountered problems when registering project/item templates. We create this file during our install.

If a re-install of VS still has this problem, then there's probably a bigger problem with the machine.

You could try running devenv /resetskippkgs and see if that makes things better. It almost looks like VS disabled everything

Jacques

Comment: You're right, it must have been a machine problem. After posting I realized SQL Mgmt Studio and Windows Media Player were also kaput. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

I've been spending almost a day trying to fix exactly this issue on VS2010, running all existing devenv switches (from Resetsettings/ResetSkipPkgs/Safemode), repairing and reinstalling VS and SP1 and I finally caught it!

In short, my problem (and I guess yours too) relies in a registry ACL on HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib{91A74EB0-EFA0-482B-B43C-35CFC74B275F}, that is indeed "Microsoft Development Environment Properties 8.0".
If you add everyone on FullAccess to this registry key from an interactive regedit (use psexec.exe -i -s regedit.exe to start it elevated), everything restarts working back.

VS throws when it shows the new project dialog a TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED exception from EnvDTE80.DTE2.get_Properties() just after accessing to "Environment.ProjectsAndSolution", because it cannot then access to the environment.

I don't know how those ACLs got screwed up, but I hope this can help someone to avoid spending hours on it and beeing stuck reading posts saying "your (BUILD) machine has a serious problem"...
HTH

Comment: And if you followup with other errors, like my case cannot open VB.NET projects references with: 

"Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'EnvDTE.ProjectItemsEvents'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{22800963-2811-410D-BF87-A7808EAC977D}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE))."

You may need to fix your registry ACLs too on HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{B4CB32F8-F8DC-11D2-A4AE-00C04F68FC81} to allow your user...HTH

Answer (score 0):

In some esoteric cases, the key {91A74EB0-EFA0-482B-B43C-35CFC74B275F} cannot be deleted by permissions issues even when running regedit with administrator permissions.

In these cases do the following:

1. Use the utility tool *RunAsSystem*

   https://www.raymond.cc/blog/full-control-permission-to-delete-or-edit-restricted-windows-registry/
2. Delete the key {91A74EB0-EFA0-482B-B43C-35CFC74B275F}