# Visual Studio 2010 New Project window is not showing installed project

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I re-installed visual studio 2010 many times, until i re-install the windows and then VS 2010 premium. but still i have same problem. Visual studio new project window does not show any project type, it is just blank new project window. this became a very serious problem for me. can any one help me. thanks in advance

As i am new user that's why i cannot add image. i found the same problem on
[Why is my Visual Studio 2010 New Project dialog broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690568/why-is-my-visual-studio-2010-new-project-dialog-broken)
Here you can find image
But i tried that answer but it does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

the solution to it

Goto Tools> Import Export Settings> Reset all settings> No> then choose any three other than project management